# My splash screen keeps on crashing and force closing the app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, splash-screen

My app keeps on crashing upon startup. Please check my code. I was doing an automatic login on my splash screen. Please help me, this is for my thesis.

**splash.class**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import static com.example.mgimoro.dietgo.Database.TABLE_NAME;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
Database database;
int id=0;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    initialize();
}
public void initialize(){
    db=helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT ID FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE ID = (ID)";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(query));
    }else{}
    if (id<0){
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, Onboard.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }else{
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, mainmenu.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
      }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your question accordingly. Please share the stacktrace that causes your app to crash.

Comment: in order to help we need to see the logcat error

Comment: you need to learn how to debug your code

Comment: show your Logcat

Comment: show your LOGS .

Answer (score 1):

### Main Issue

You aren't instantiating the **helper** object so it is null, when you attempt `db=helper.getReadableDatabase();` in the `initialize` method.

As such you need to instantiate the helper object before `db=helper.getReadableDatabase();`.

However, you wouldn't be able to instantiate **helper** as it's been defined with a type of SQLiteOpenHelper, as per `SQLiteOpenHelper helper;. It should be a type of a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper, as such you should instead use something like,`mySqliteOpenHelperSubclass = myDBHelper`.

Then in the `initialize` method instantiate the `myDBhelper` object by constructing it. e.g. `myDBHelper = new mySqliteOpenHelperSubclass(this);` and then you could use `myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Currently your code would result in a null pointer exception.

### Supplementary Issue

`id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(query));` would result in an exception (if any rows exist in the table) as `c.getColumnIndex()` is being told to find the column index of the column named **SELECT ID FROM your_table_name WHERE ID = (ID)**, which would not exist.

The result would be -1, which is an invalid index and the exception would indicate an invalid offset of -1.

e.g.

```
09-07 21:16:24.903 1546-1546/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{so52226238.so52226238/so52226238.so52226238.Splash}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

### Working Example

#### 1 Database.java

The following assumes that **Database.java** (assuming that it is the subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper) is :-

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insert(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,name);
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }
}
```

- Obviously your version may be more complex

#### 2 Splash.java

The following will fix the issues (refer to comments) :-

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    // SQLiteOpenHelper helper; <<<<<<<<<< DELETED
    Database database;
    int id=0;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        initialize();
    }
    public void initialize(){
        database = new Database(this); //<<<<< instantiate Database helper
        db=database.getReadableDatabase();
        database.insert("Fred"); //<<<<<<<<<< Added to test with data.
        String query = "SELECT ID FROM " + TABLE_NAME
                + " WHERE ID = (ID)";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)); //<<<<<<<<<< ID column
            //id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID")); //<<<<<<<<<< as above but uses hard coded column name
        }else{}
        c.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< YOU SHOULD ALWAYS CLOSE A CURSOR WHEN FINISHED WITH IT
        if (id<0){
            Log.d("IDINFO","ID not found."); //<<<<<<<<<< used for simplicity
            /*
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, Onboard.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
            */
        }else{
            Log.d("IDINFO","ID found."); //<<<<<<<<<< used for simplicity
            /*

            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, mainmenu.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
            */
        }
    }
}
```

- **Note** The attempt to start the activities has been commented out for ease and for demonstration.

Comment: I always admire your effort on answering, you're often (if not always) answering with precise and detailed description. Great works!